# View OpenMP environment variable on ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, openmp

I am learning OpenMP API. I wanted to know how can I view OpenMP Environment variables, e.g. OMP_NUM_THREADS in ubuntu. I know that I can change their values using `export` but I do not know how to view their values. I tried `echo $OMP_NUM_THREADS` but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed see them by using `echo`.

```
 echo $OMP_NUM_THREADS
```

is the proper thing to do. You didn't see anything, because the variable is not defined. You must first define it yourself. The variable does not exist in the environment by default.

As Jim Cownie comments, you can get a list of all OMP variables currently defined in the environment by

```
 env | grep OMP
```

`env` alone prints all variables in.

Comment: Or use env https://linux.die.net/man/1/env Note the "If no COMMAND, print the resulting environment", so just executing env with no arguments prints the whole environment.